# My fiance's iPhone 4 is still running on iOS 5, now that 6.1.3 has been released can I upgrade her to 6.1.2 so she can use evasion?

Tags: ios

I have an iPhone 4S, CDMA version, iOS 6.1 jailbroken. Therefore no real need to upgrade at the moment. However my fiance's iPhone 4, I have heard, could benefit from an upgrade to iOS 6.1.2 from the iOS 5 she is currently running (jailbroken with absynthe). I was going to do this today- then I found out iOS 6.1.3 was been released, which is not able to be jailbroken. Is she stuck or can she upgrade to 6.1.2 somehow still and use evasions jailbreak?

Comment: Chances are you are stuck. Hopefully they will release a 6.1.3 jailbreak soon.

Comment: It's not much of a stuck, though. Unless you need a fix for the Exchange bug, you're fine sitting at 6.1.2.

Comment: @Zo219, I think you might have mis-read the original question.  The original poster has iOS 5, so the two options are: stay at iOS5 (jailbroken), or upgrade to 6.1.3 (not jailbroken).  Staying at 6.1.2 is not an option.

Answer (score -3):

you can download ipsw file for 6.1.2.  apparantly there is a way to do this for iphone4 but newer hardware will not allow it.

Comment: How should the asker proceed once he/she has downloaded the ipsw file?